# How to know the used buffer size of a SourceQueue in akka?

Tags: scala, queue, akka-stream

So I'm a fan of using `Source.queue` and now I want to monitor it, to know how much of the buffer it's being used at certain point. Yet I haven't seen a way to know such info. Only thing which comes to mind is a workaround in which I have a mutable number to which I add when I offer an element, and subtract, when the operation has been completed.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing an curious about what you ended up doing ?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the [`QueueSource`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/Sources.scala) class to provide a materialized queue that exposes its internal buffer size. This can be done by creating a new trait - e.g.

```
trait SourceQueueWithCompleteAndSize[T] extends SourceQueueWithComplete[T] {
  def size: Int
}
```

Then, in the final part of the stage (see the original [code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/Sources.scala#L173) for reference), you need to provide your new trait implementation instead of the `SourceQueueWithComplete`. You should be able to access the size of the internal buffer with the `used` method.

```
(stageLogic, new SourceQueueWithCompleteAndSize[T] {
  // other methods implementations

  override def size: Int = stageLogic.buffer.used // NEW BIT
})
```

It's a fair amount of code to copy, but it might be better than adding an external counter around your stage. Might as well be a valid contribution to [akka-stream-contrib](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib).